# Close all open tipsy tooltip with unique selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

In my project I'm using jquery tipsy tooltp to validate the fields of a form.
I would like to hide all open tooltips in one shot without having to specify the id of each element, but unfortunately I can not.
I tried this way, but the buttons hide2 and hide3 not work properly.

```
<p><input type="text" name="name" id="name" rel="ttp" /></p>
<p><input type="text" name="sname" id="sname" rel="ttp" /></p>
<p><input type="text" name="email" id="email" rel="ttp" /></p>

<input type="button" value="show" id="show_ttp">
<input type="button" value="hide" id="hide_ttp">
<input type="button" value="hide2" id="hide2_ttp">
<input type="button" value="hide3" id="hide3_ttp">
```

JS

```
$('[rel=ttp]').tipsy({trigger: 'manual', gravity: 'w'});

$("#show_ttp").click(function(){
   $('#name').attr('title', 'name').tipsy('show');
   $('#sname').attr('title', 'surname').tipsy('show');
   $('#email').attr('title', 'email').tipsy('show');
});

$("#hide_ttp").click(function(){
   $('#name').tipsy('hide');
   $('#sname').tipsy('hide');
   $('#email').tipsy('hide');
});

$("#hide2_ttp").click(function(){
   $('*').tipsy('hide');
});

$("#hide3_ttp").click(function(){
  $('[rel=ttp]').tipsy('hide');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tm9V2/

How could I do? thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To hide all the tipsy tooltip just use .tipsy class as a selector and hide it using jquery `hide()`

**CODE :**

```
$("#hide2_ttp").click(function(){
    $('.tipsy').hide();
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/koushikKumar/tm9V2/11/)

Comment: Very clean. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @PaoloRossi glad to help you friend

Comment: I feel like `$('.tipsy').remove();` is even cleaner as it doesn't pollute your `DOM` if you show and hide them multiple times

Answer (score 3):

My be this is what you are looking for

```
  $("#hide3_ttp").click(function(){
        $('[rel=ttp]').each(function(index, element){$(element).tipsy('hide');});
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but the code of @Kamesh seems cleaner

Answer (score 1):

I don't know to use this tooltip plugin but you can hide these object with using force.

Since tipsy plugin removes its object with its hide method, you can use jQuery `.remove()` function aswell and don't forgot tipsy appends objects with javascript, so use `$(document).on` to manipulate them. check this:

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tm9V2/6/)

```
$(document).on('click','#hide2_ttp',function(){
    $('.tipsy').eq(1).remove();
});

$(document).on('click','#hide3_ttp',function(){
    $('.tipsy').eq(0).remove();
});
```

Edit: for hiding all tooltips which are open, use this function:

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tm9V2/9/)

```
$(document).on('click','#hideallopen',function(){
    $('.tipsy').remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I must hide all tooltips in one shot with only unique selector

Comment: @PaoloRossi check my answer again, since tipsy plugin removes its object with its `hide` method, you can use jQuery `.remove()` function aswell and don't forgot tipsy appends objects with `javascript`, so use `$(document).on` to manipulate them.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap up all the elements in a div/form/span and change your following code :

```
$("#hide2_ttp").click(function(){
    $('*').tipsy('hide');
});
```

to

```
$("#hide2_ttp").click(function(){

 $('#elements input').each(function(){
        $(this).tipsy('hide');
    });
});
```

where 'elements' is the id for the wrapper of your inputs.

*In this way you can have multiple group of inputs and close their tipsy separately.*

FIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/tm9V2/8/